# trying to input values to the selected editTexts

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener

I recently started using android studio. So I come across a problem, which is like this: I have 2 buttons and 5 editTexts. Using onClickListener, I am trying to input values to the editTexts. But the problem is I can make only one editText to listen what button I am pressing. If I use different onClickListener for 5 editTexts, only the last one is responding to the buttons (which is obvious). I want to happen like this: Whatever etitText I select, when I press a button, the value will reflect on only that one. But it is not working. I was hoping something like a if statement, where if I select a specific editText the onClickListener will respond to that.

I created this following method.

```
private void selectBox(EditText e, Button b1, Button b2) {
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button) v;
            e.append(b.getText().toString());
        }
    };
    b1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    b2.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

then I want something like this in onCreate method:

```
if(editText1 is selecte`enter code here`d in the emulator) {
 selectBox(editText1, button1, button2);
 } else if(editText2 is selected in the emulator) {
 selectBox(editText2, button1, button2);
 } ......
```

How would I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: You need to declare an id to the object in the view, in this way you will know which object are going to receive the data. Go to the XML. And add android:id="@+id/editText_0". Iff possible show us the Activity code and XML(Layout).

Comment: @Suehtam I have declared ids for every object in layout.

Comment: @Suehtam the below answer looks right, I just don't know kotlin, so I can not process what method to use, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Here You Go !

```
fun handleText() {
        var flag: Int
        txtBox1.setOnClickListener {
            flag = 1
            if (flag == 1) {
                button.setOnClickListener {
                    txtBox1.text = "add text to field 1"
                }
            }
        }
        txtBox2.setOnClickListener {
            flag = 2
            if (flag == 2) {
                button.setOnClickListener {
                    txtBox2.text = "add text to field 2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Post: I don't like Java as much as I like Kotlin. That's why your question is Java and my answer is Kotlin.

Comment: I tested it on my own computer, its working check and try once. And for you information its not always true, because its Kotlin not Java.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use setOnClickListener on editText, it is giving error that it needs an argument

Comment: I don't know how kotlin works, so I am confused.